# Получить дату из DatePicker (Javafx, fxml)

Tags: javafx, datepicker

Как получить выбранную дату из `DatePicker`?

Часть `fxml` кода:

```
<children>
     <Button fx:id="showLast" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Show last 10" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
     <Button fx:id="showAll" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Show all" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
     <Button fx:id= "showBetweenDates" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="199.0" text="Show Between Dates" />
     <DatePicker fx:id= "endDate" prefWidth="187.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
     <DatePicker fx:id= "startDate"  onAction="#startDatePickerAction" prefWidth="186.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
     <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="57.0" text="Start Date" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
     <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="53.0" text="End Date" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
</children>
```

и мой код контроллера:

```
public class HistoryController implements Initializable {
    private final SalesSystemDAO dao;
    private LocalDate start;
    private LocalDate end;
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(HistoryController.class);

    @FXML
    private Button showBetweenDates;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker startDatePicker;
    @FXML
    private DatePicker endDatePicker;
    @FXML
    private TableView<SoldItem> purchaseHistoryTableView;

    public HistoryController(SalesSystemDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    @FXML
    private void startDatePickerAction() {
        start = startDatePicker.getValue(); // тут выдаёт ошибку
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        log.info("History initializing");
        // TODO: implement
    }
}
```

Comment: `тут выдаёт ошибку` -- какую?

Comment: ошибка Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, возникает именно при выборе  числа. До этого всё работает нормально. Если поменять startDatePicker.getValue() на любой другой метод DatePicker ошибка та же.

Comment: А разве название аннотированной переменной не должно совпадать с `fx:id`? В `fxml` у Вас `DatePicker fx:id= "startDate"`, а в контроллере `private DatePicker startDatePicker;`. Попробуйте в `fxml` заменить `fx:id= "startDate"` на `fx:id= "startDatePicker"`.

Comment: Дааа)))теперь всё работает! Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Названия аннотированных переменных должны совпадать с `fx:id` в `fxml`-файле.

В `fxml` замените `<DatePicker fx:id= "startDate"` на `<DatePicker fx:id= "startDatePicker"`.

Ну и с другими компонентами аналогично.